# Listing and viewing contents of Azure Storage containers with Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, storage

In Azure a container will be made for each user in Azure Storage, I want to be able to list the container and view the size of the content to ensure it does not exceed a certain limit.  Is it possible to do this with Azure Logic Apps?  I am not finding functions to do so.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is possible through logic apps. You can use 'Get Blob Metadata (V2)' to get all the properties of the files and if you are trying to get the content, you can use 'Get blob content (V2)'. To reproduce this I first created 3 containers (i.e., Container1, Container2, and Container3) and uploaded a few files into these containers with different sizes. To get the list of all the containers I have used `Lists blobs in the root folder  (V2)` and used `Lists blobs (V2)` taking the path from the previous step to iterate blobs inside the containers.

[image]

In the next step I'm using `Get Blob Metadata (V2)` to get the properties of each blob using `list blobs path`.

[image]

Then using `Condition` action I'm extracting the blobs which are less than 9128 bytes and storing all this data into variables.

[image]

Finally, I'm using compose connector to view all the files along with size and path.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can try using the below code view to test in your environment

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('FilesWithinLimit')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@variables('FilesOutOfLimit')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "FilesOutOfLimit": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FilesOutOfLimit",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "FilesWithinLimit": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "FilesWithinLimit": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FilesWithinLimit",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Condition": {
                                "actions": {
                                    "Append_to_FilesWithinLimit": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "name": "FilesWithinLimit",
                                            "value": {
                                                "Name": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['DisplayName']}",
                                                "Path": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['Path']}",
                                                "Size": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['Size']}"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {},
                                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                    }
                                },
                                "else": {
                                    "actions": {
                                        "Append_to_FilesOutOfLimit": {
                                            "inputs": {
                                                "name": "FilesOutOfLimit",
                                                "value": {
                                                    "Name": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['DisplayName']}",
                                                    "Path": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['Path']}",
                                                    "Size": "@{body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['Size']}"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "runAfter": {},
                                            "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "expression": {
                                    "and": [
                                        {
                                            "lessOrEquals": [
                                                "@body('Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)')?['Size']",
                                                9128
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "If"
                            },
                            "Get_Blob_Metadata_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_2')?['Path']))}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}",
                            "queries": {
                                "nextPageMarker": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_in_the_root_folder__(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_in_the_root_folder__(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_in_the_root_folder__(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "FilesOutOfLimit": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```